# What is the error in this code?..It always go in else

Tags: php, mysql, database, session, login-script

Why is this code not working?

It always go in else and set $_SESSION['wronglogin']=1;
it is a login script which takes input of email-id and password and then checks that if any such thing exists then it should start $_SESSION['loggedin'] otherwise $_SESSION['wronglogin'].
I have tried a lot but i am just not getting it

```
$_SESSION['login-id']=$loginid;
$_SESSION['loginpassword']=$loginpassword;


$loginid = stripslashes($loginid);
$loginpassword = stripslashes($loginpassword);
$loginid = mysql_real_escape_string($loginid);
$loginpassword = mysql_real_escape_string($loginpassword);

$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "moodabsz_naman", "database") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("moodabsz_database",$con) or die(mysql_error());

$sql="SELECT * 
FROM  user 
WHERE  `email_id` =  '$loginid'
AND  `password` =  '$loginpassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
if($count==1){
    $_SESSION['loggedin']=1;


    mysql_close($con);

    header('location: index.php');

}
else {

    $_SESSION['wronglogin']=1;
    echo "Wrong Username or Password";

    mysql_close($con);

    header('Location: index.php');
}
```

Comment: Output the query and try to run it manually. Probably your database has no matching entry.

Comment: Have you checked the values you save in the session initially?
$_SESSION['login-id']=$loginid;
$_SESSION['loginpassword']=$loginpassword;

Comment: it do tried it atleast 10 times myfriend

Comment: either that or the `$_SESSION` variables aren't populated. I don't see a `session_start()` anywhere

Comment: Also you should not be using `mysql_*` functions as they are deprecated. Use PDO (http://php.net/PDO) and paramatized queries. Your code suffers from SQL Injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: Are you sure that you have only one row returned from your SQL request?

Comment: apart from a comment about using PDO and not storing your password in plain, have you tried to actually run the query in mysql? Or, when you are using x-debug, have you checked the query that is acutally executed?

Comment: `session_start()`? can help. Also don't use `mysql_*` because the use of this extension is discouraged. Also notice that you validate 2 times. You can do this at once like `if(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  user WHERE  email_id =  '$loginid' AND password =  '$loginpassword' LIMIT 1")) echo 'I have data so i may pass';`

Comment: you can also use var_dump($_SESSION); to see what is contained in the session array. then you'll see any values

Comment: session_start has been declared in my code @Bondye

Comment: @dmaij tried running in my sql there it was working

Comment: The problem is certainly either your _SESSION variables or your query. Check `mysql_error` after the call to `mysql_query()`

Comment: perhaps try     if($count>0) { helps?

Comment: You probably have multiple rows, it will go in the else because you are checking `$count==1`. Add a `LIMIT 1` to the query.

Comment: @Bondye that did work sir thanks but wts problem with this one

Comment: No Multiple rows for Sure deff.@dmaij,@MrCode

Comment: @Bondye the code in your comment has a serious problem, you should delete it.

Comment: No that just worked for meif("SELECT * 
FROM  user 
WHERE  `email_id` =  '$loginid'
AND  `password` =  '$loginpassword'"){
$_SESSION['loggedin']=1;
@MrCode

Comment: @MrCode Substructure criticism. This piece of code is an example, never blind copy code, but try to understand it first.

Comment: @Bondye your code doesn't verify the email and password, it lets EVERYONE login without needing a record in the table. I'd say that's pretty serious. You might aswell replace your code with `if(true)` because that's essentially what it does.

Comment: @MrCode Check again. It wil check if user + password combi is found. If this results in true, the user does exists. Nothing wrong here.

Comment: @mrCode is Right i hv jst checked that he is totaly right it do the same it is letting everyone login

Comment: @MrCode i hv tried all the things u said the email do exist in database and tried setting limit too but same problem persists

Comment: @Bondey i just got it actualy the thing is in ur code it executes the statement and if statement(which always will) is executed it will take it as TRUE

Comment: @user1901478 can you add `die($sql)` before the query, then copy the exact result into phpMyAdmin or direct on MySQL and tell us if there are rows and how many.

Comment: die($sql) before whole query or just mysql @MrCode

Comment: @user1901478 it's not supposed to fix it, it's to debug. You need to see what the query looks like and you need to run it direct on the db to see how many rows and if any errors.

Comment: @MrCode in phpMy admin it is displaying the result

Comment: @user1901478 remove the `die($sql)`, then change to `$result=mysql_query($sql) or die('error: ' . mysql_error());` then run your code, and tell us what it outputs

Comment: @MrCode its Quite surprising its still the same that means its reading data i guess

Comment: This is just ugly. You guys should really be discussing this via [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/) if you're going to go back and forth like this. And @user1901478 you really need to read up on some tutorials on how this sort of thing is done. It's very common and you sound like you don't have a good foundation for this yet. Your current code is extremely poorly written and has several security flaws in it.

Comment: @mrcode any further soln

Comment: @user1901478 what makes you think it goes in the else? Do you see `Wrong Username or Password` on the page?

Comment: @mrcode yes i have set it so that if if(isset($_SESSION['wronglogin']))
{echo $_SESSION['login-id'];
session_unset();

echo "Wrong Username or Password";

}

Comment: Is that in the else? Check your error log for errors, and show how the username and password are retrieved, $_POST?

Comment: yes actually   if (isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] == "Log In"){
$loginid = $_POST['email-id'];
$loginpassword = $_POST['password'];
if ($_POST['email-id']!="" && $_POST['password']!="")
{

$_SESSION['login-id']=$loginid;
$_SESSION['loginpassword']=$loginpassword;


$loginid = stripslashes($loginid);
$loginpassword = stripslashes($loginpassword);
$loginid = mysql_real_escape_string($loginid);
$loginpassword = mysql_real_escape_string($loginpassword);

Comment: @MrCode yes actually if (isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] == "Log In"){ $loginid = $_POST['email-id']; $loginpassword = $_POST['password']; if ($_POST['email-id']!="" && $_POST['password']!="") { $_SESSION['login-id']=$loginid; $_SESSION['loginpassword']=$loginpassword; $loginid = stripslashes($loginid); $loginpassword = stripslashes($loginpassword); $loginid = mysql_real_escape_string($loginid); $loginpassword = mysql_real_escape_string($loginpassword);

Comment: @MrCode i just got the problem the problem was being created by sql injection commands

Comment: @mrcode but sir if i can not to use sql injection so what should i do for protecting from the same

Comment: @user1901478 how have you solved it, by removing `mysql_real_escape_string()`?

Comment: @Mrcode  yes but now user can ener evil commands so what should i do to protect it which was indeed work of sql injection

Comment: @user1901478 switch to PDO and use a parameterised query, tutorial here: http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers

Comment: @MrCode thanks alot for your help! this was just because i am qite young 15 compare to guyz here so just a begginer only sir

Answer (score 0):

can you copy the output of this,

```
<?php
$_SESSION['login-id']=$loginid;
$_SESSION['loginpassword']=$loginpassword;


$loginid = stripslashes($loginid);
$loginpassword = stripslashes($loginpassword);
$loginid = mysql_real_escape_string($loginid);
$loginpassword = mysql_real_escape_string($loginpassword);

$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "moodabsz_naman", "database") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("moodabsz_database",$con) or die(mysql_error());

$sql="SELECT * 
FROM  `user` 
WHERE  `email_id` =  '$loginid'
AND  `password` =  '$loginpassword'";

$result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

echo 'Debug::Count-'.$count;

if($count==1){
    $_SESSION['loggedin']=1;


    mysql_close($con);

   // header('location: index.php');

}
else {

    $_SESSION['wronglogin']=1;
    echo "Wrong Username or Password";

    mysql_close($con);

    //header('Location: index.php');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The above code is not working because missing the [session_start()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) function which should be placed at the first line of your PHP code.

```
<?php
session_start();
/*

The rest of your code

*/
?>
```

Comment: sorry sir actually i alreay mentioned that i am running it with that only

Comment: Sorry, I realized that you had not initialized your session.